# i have phpunit test that directly interect with database and when assert fail it stop test and don't pass to the nest assert

Tags: phpunit

I have PHPUnit test that directly interacts with database and when the assert fails, it throws an error and then stops the test and doesn't execute the next assert.

What I need is that when an assert fails, it should pass to the next assert and throw an error at the end of the test.

My biggest issue is because I am interacting with database, when I make Insert, Update, GetAll, GetbyID at the end of test I always make Delete.

I know there other ways of testing without interacting with the database but I was asked to make a test that interacts with the database, so what I need something like (SOFT ASSERT-TRY CATCH) in PHPUnit.

So please anyone that has an answer help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a configuration file:

```
<phpunit
     stopOnError="false"
     stopOnFailure="false">
```

Set those two attributes to false, or if running off the command line use

```
--stop-on-error
--stop-on-failure
```